# Robotframework: How to receive a list of all items inside a select field?

Tags: xml, select, xpath, robotframework

I am currently stucked on the current situation while doing Test Automation on Robotframework. I kindly request for your assistance.

I have got a select field of the following style:

```
<select name="TestSelect" size="8" id="TextSelectInfoBox"     onchange="JavaScript:setTestSelect( TestSelect1, TestSelect2 );">                    
                    <option value="TestOption1"> First Entry</option>
</select>
```

I now wish to check, if the select item does contain the value TestOption1.

I found the hint on this website, that I could use the "List Should Contain" Keyword.

For this, I defined the variable:

${XPath_AccessList}   xpath=//select[@name="TestSelect"]

Thanks to a quick reply on my question, I am now able to use

```
Page should contain element   path=//select[@name="TestSelect"]/option[@value="TestOption1"]
```

To get my first tests passed. Nevertheless, I would like to know if there is a comfortable way to fetch the options of such select field as a list for late usage of the "List Should Contain Value" keyword.

While searching on the RobotFramework guides, I did only find the XML Library which seems to have functionality like "Get Child Elements" to possibly offer a solution, but I am a bit sceptical when seeing that it needs a "source" parameter, which I cannot provide.

Thank you in advance for your help, if you do have any further question, I will try to provide such.

Best regards,

Tony

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`List should contain` only works on lists. You're not giving it a list, you're giving it an xpath. You would need to fetch a list of web elements in order to use `List should contain`.

To verify that the element exists, use [Page Should Contain Element](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/doc/Selenium2Library.html#Page%20Should%20Contain%20Element) and give it an xpath for the option element.

My xpath knowledge is a bit weak, but I think it would look like this:

```
Page should contain element    xpath=//select[@name="TestSelect"]/option[@value="TestOption1"]
```

If you want to get a list of web elements that match a locator you can use [Get Web Elements](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/doc/Selenium2Library.html#Get%20Webelements)

Comment: Thank you a lot for the quick reply! That helped out to get the test case pass now. Still searching for a way to fetch the options as a list for optimization, though.

Comment: @Aldaris: to get a list of web elements you can use [Get web elements](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/doc/Selenium2Library.html#Get%20Webelements)

Comment: Thank You A Lot. I will look into the same.